# How to install osmdroid libraries for android studio coding?

Tags: android, ubuntu, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am trying to do a tutorial for making an Android application using osmdroid with android Studio, but I didn't succeed to use the library I download on https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

How can I install these libraries for compiling my app ?

Thanks you very much in advance for your help !

ps: I am running on Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Are you getting a specific error or problem while trying to use it? If you are using Gradle to build you can follow the short instruction for adding the Gradle dependency and that will automatically include the library for you.

Comment: See the [osmdroid wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki), especially [How to add the osmdroid library via Gradle](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle) or [How to include OsmDroid in a Maven Android project](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-include-OsmDroid-in-a-Maven-Android-project) depending on your personal preferences.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but my questions are following  :


1. Where do I have to put the folder download at: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid ?


2.Which version I have to put in this command:
`dependencies {
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:(INSERT_VERSION_HERE):release@aar'
}` instead of 'INSERT_VERSION_HERE'.

Comment: help me please !